# Writing a typescript module for mac and win while using platform-specific dependency

Tags: node.js, typescript

I'm working on a typescript-based build pipeline for nw.js and electron apps. The build pipeline supports both windows and mac targets.

When compiled on windows, the build pipeline should use windows-specific npm packages to access the windows registry and other windows-specific tools.

When compiled on mac, the build pipeline should use mac-specific npm packages to compile .dmg files and other mac-specific tools.

These platform specific tools are not installable on other platforms. I know how to add these to [`optionalDependencies` in my `package.json`](https://yarnpkg.com/lang/en/docs/dependency-types/), but my problem is importing the libraries even though both systems will have unavailable dependencies referenced in import statements.

How do I write a module that uses both of these things, even though the .dmg library isn't available on windows, and the windows registry library isn't available on mac?

Certainly someone at google working on angular projects has figured out a way to utilize platform-specific typescript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At this time there is no way to dynamically import modules, but it is on its way at [stage 3](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-dynamic-import#import) of the next version of ECMAScript. It will basically work like a Promise:

```
import("some-module").then(someModule => {
   someModule.doSomething();
});
```

Since TypeScript aims to be a [superset of ECMAScript](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/TypeScript-Design-Goals), it should include this feature.

---

In the mean time you can use `require()` for dynamic module loading:

```
./src
 |-- build-tool.ts
 |-- windows-build-tool.ts
 |-- mac-build-tool.ts
 |-- index.ts
```

***build-tool.ts***

```
import * as os from "os";

export interface IBuildTool {
    run(): void;
}

const getBuildTool = (platform: string) => {

    switch (platform) {

        case "win32":
            return require("./windows-build-tool").default;

        case "darwin":
            return require("./mac-build-tool").default;

        default:
            throw new Error(`No build tool exists for '${platform}' platform`);
    }
};

const platform = os.platform();

export default getBuildTool(platform);
```

***windows-build-tool.ts***

```
import { IBuildTool } from "./build-tool";

// Import Windows-specific modules

export default class WindowsBuildTool implements IBuildTool {

    run() {
        console.log("Running Windows build tools...");
    }
}
```

***mac-build-tool.ts***

```
import { IBuildTool } from "./build-tool";

// Import Mac-specific modules

export default class MacBuildTool implements IBuildTool {

    run() {
        console.log("Running Mac build tools...");
    }
}
```

***index.ts***

```
import BuildTool from "./build-tool";

const buildTool = new BuildTool();

buildTool.run();
```